# Sending the same proposal to multiple funding agencies

Tags: peer-review, funding, research-proposal

I am planning to submit a proposal for possible funding. There are three sources of funding I can apply for, and unfortunately the evaluation periods all three overlap. Typically there exists an option to state this while submitting. I am wondering if such a statement has any impact on the chances of being funded (of the three grants, I much prefer a specific one). Moreover, two of the agencies uses external reviewers and since my proposed work builds heavily on the previous efforts of three persons (one of them a prolific reviewer), there is a risk in reviewer overlap. I wonder how a reviewer would perceive this. In particular, would a reviewer be less inclined to recommend a second proposal for funding if they have already recommended a first on the same topic? PS I was advised not to make any statement of overlap. Is this an  unofficial custom?

Comment: Talk to the program officers from your funding sources.  Some funding sources encourage simultaneous submission; others discourage it or even forbid it.  There is no universal rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is better to not do it. At least simultaneously (might be ok if the proposal was rejected).
If you absolutely have to go ahead, try to fine-tune and change the proposal as much as possible according to the agency requirements.

Comment: I am sort of in a predicament where I have to submit at least two of them. I could skip the third.